# Airflow: how to get response from Big query output for data availability and based on result kick off task/subdags

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

Requirement is [kick off dag based on data availability from upstream/dependent tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4uEf.png)

While condition check data availability (in the tables at Big query for n number of iteration) to check data available or not. If data available then kick off subdag/task else continue in loop.

It would be great to see an clear example how to use BigQueryOperator or `BigQueryValueCheckOperator' and then execute big query something like this

{Code}
SELECT
  1
FROM
  
WHERE
  datetime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE())
  AND TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),1,'day'))
LIMIT
  1
{Code}

If query output is 1 (that means data available for today's load) then kick off dag else continue in loop as shown in attached diagram link.

Does anyone had setup such design in Airflow dag.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the BaseSensorOperator and BigQueryTableSensor to implement your own Sensor for it. https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/airflow/operators/sensors.html

> Sensor operators keep executing at a time interval and succeed when a
>   criteria is met and fail if and when they time out.

BigQueryTableSensor just checks whether table exists or not but did check the data in the table. It might be something like this:

```
task1>>YourSensor>>task2
```

Comment: Thanks Chengzi, but looks like `BigQueryTableSensor ` does not applicable for querying table for specific condition as it just check table availability as you mentioned.   I need to execute query like this to ensure there is data for today and then kick off dag.  If query return 1 then data is available for today else 0.                                                                               SELECT
  1
FROM
  <schemaname.tablename>
WHERE
  datetime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE())
  AND TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),1,'day'))
LIMIT
  1

Comment: @Virat Hi. Were you able to solve this? I am looking for something similar.